# Visual Studio 2022 serious bug

Tags: debugging, bin

Added new folder in Solution Explorer. populated it with multiple image files.  Added all to Build - resource.  All items showed up as build to resource file.  This was added to an existing set of folders all holding image files.  program logic set them to Image.source in xaml.  showed correctly in xaml editor.  Use Uri bmpimage to reset image at execution time.  All seemed well with debug/build. i.e. clean build
However, at debug session. even though Uri bmpimage packed image correctly, it did not show the image file. Urikind set as 'relative'
I tested logic by copying the new images into existing folder that previously always showed correct images at debug session.  This is where the visual studio bug exists....    it still showed the original images in that folder even though I had replaced them with new images.  at first glance seemed like a cache issue.  So, rebooted machine after pulling off a/c cord to ensure no left over cache.  Reran program with same result.  After multiple tests and configuration resets, I tried one last thing. **I DELETED THE BIN/DEBUG FOLDER**.  Incredibly this solved the problem.  Someone should make Microsoft aware of this problem, as I wasted 2+ hours working through it.  At minimum, if there is a legitimate reason for this, document it and explain it....

Comment: Have you reported it to Microsoft?

Comment: Well, I was hoping this was not an outlier and other users had experienced similar problem.  I will report to Microsoft but do not hold out much hope for resolution as their standard response is we need more information to replicate the problem.  There is no additional information I can provide as it is not a programming problem but a problem with the debug/build process not updating the dll in the bin/debug folder.

Comment: Well, I was hoping this was not an outlier and other users had experienced similar problem.  I will report to Microsoft but do not hold out much hope for resolution as their standard response is we need more information to replicate the problem.  There is no additional information I can provide as it is not a programming problem but a problem with the debug/build process not updating the dll in the bin/debug folder.  Clearly an issue for their internal system programmers.  I suspect a problem with last VS release, as problem did not exist before that... or  possible conflict with extension.

Comment: forwarded issue to microsoft. Response from microsoft:  'bot has reclassified issue as "triage" and escalated to senior tech support team'